# Why doesn't my date comparision return true?

Tags: java

The if below never triggers, so c.after(a) must always return false. However, if I uncomment the second println, I clearly see that a is > 20050214, as I expect.

`Date a = slice.getCurrentRow().getTime();

Calendar b = Calendar.getInstance();

b.set(2005, 2, 14);

if (b.after(a)) {

    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(a));

}

//System.out.println(dateFormat.format(a));`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're passing a Date to Calendar.after(Object when). If "when" is not also a calendar, it returns always false. Try b.getTime().after(a) instead.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 4):

You are checking if 2005-02-14 > a, not the other way around.

Comment: You're right, I'm an idiot. However, this doesn't help. a gets set to every date from early 2005 to mid 2010. b.after(a) should still have triggered at some point. (Immediately would have been nice and predictable) And even if I reverse it to b.before(a), it still never happens.

Comment: @Claes: Mikko has the correct answer - you are calling b.after(a), which is Calendar.after(Object) which always returns false.
In general, the java.util.Calendar API in Java has all kinds of tricky points in it that make it hard to use - you may be better off using something like Joda Time (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're testing if b (14/02/2005) is after a (later than 14/02/2005). This is clearly not true. Do you mean:

```
if(a.after(b)) {
```

???

Comment: I do, see Avi's answer, except it isn't valid to compare the date and calender types like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar b = Calendar.getInstance();
b.set(2005, 2, 14);
```

OK, so you get a new Calendar instance and set the year, month, and day of month on it.  Quick question: What are the hour, minute, second, and millisecond set to?

Don't know?  I'll let the [JavaDoc description](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28%29) of the empty constructor for `GregorianCalendar`* explain:

> Constructs a default `GregorianCalendar`
>   using the current time in the default
>   time zone with the default locale.

So, `b` has a time component that you don't see.

If you truly want a Calendar object with no time on it, you need to initialize it like this:

```
Calendar b = new GregorianCalendar(2005, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 14, 0, 0, 0);
```

Why do it using the `GregorianCalendar` constructor instead of `b.set`?  Because `Calendar` also has a millisecond field that you would otherwise also have to clear.  In fact, you can clear fields manually on a `Calendar` instance one at a time, like this:

```
b.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
b.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
b.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
b.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

If you're going to compare them for equal dates, you might want to do this.  If you want to measure if it's just after 12:00am that day, I'd go with the `GregorianCalender` constructor method.

Note: As others have mentioned, you still need to call `b.getTime()` before comparing the two dates.

[*`GregorianCalendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is the default `Calendar` implementation returned by `Calendar.getInstance()`

Comment: Useful information, I appreciate the time you took, but I don't think it's necessarily related to my question, since I just need day-granularity, or am I missing something more?

Comment: Well, if `a` is set to 2005-02-14 00:00:00 and `b` is set to 2005-02-14 05:34:00, `b.getTime().after(a)` will be `true`.  If `a`'s time is instead 12:34:56, `b.getTime().after(a)` will be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`b.after(a)` returns true iff `b` occurs after `a`.

If `a > 2005-02-14` I suppose `a` occurs *after* `2005-02-14`.

```
|-------|---------------|-------|
   b=20050214     <     a
```

---

As you mention in a comment, you can't compare Calendar with Date in that way. The reason the compiler doesn't complain, is because Calendar.after accepts an arbitrary `Object`.

The solution is to do

```
b.getTime().after(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted creates a new `Calendar` named `b` set to 2005 March 14, because months in Java `Date` and `Calendar` are [zero-based](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) (January is 0).  Use the `Calendar` constants if you want to avoid this (i.e. `Calendar.FEBRUARY`).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, I wasn't aware.